# Tooltip on combox Item

Tags: c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I want a tool tip on the drop down list  for combox items. I have a combobox and showing combobox item in that combobox on selected index change of drop down, but it is note helping me too much.

Since my dropdown size is small, and items in the dropdown are very big, it's become difficult for users to select the proper value by seeing this.

If tooltip shown on the individual item, it could be very useful.

If any budy knows answer , Please reply.

Comment: how to automatically adjust the size of the drop down list of a combo box to fit the size of the longest string in its items.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for this.  An example in code would be:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBox1);
```

You can then tie this code to the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

**NOTE:** Your `ComboBox` name may differ from mine.

Comment: I'm using Compact framework 2.0 where there is no control called tooltip. But I have solve this problem by expanding the combobox when user click on combobox.